# Covariance of a Portfolio with a Stock in that Portfolio

Tags: probability, finance, covariance, actuarial-science

> A portfolio consists of three stocks: $X, Y, Z$. $40\%$ of the portfolio is invested in $X$, $40\%$ in $Y$, and $20\%$ in $Z$. The three stocks are uncorrelated. The volatilities of the three stocks are $0.27, 0.23, 0.44$, respectively. Calculate the correlation of $X$ with the portfolio.

In the provided solution, this is said:

> The covariance of $X$ with the portfolio, since $X$ is uncorrelated with the other two stocks, is $0.4(0.27^2) = 0.02916$.

What justifies this statement? As far as I can tell this does not follow from $\mathrm{Cov}(A,B) = \mathrm{E}[AB] - \mathrm{E}[A]\mathrm{E}[B]$, and I don't know what other tools could be used here.

Comment: You need to use `\%` for the percent signs to show up.

Comment: What definition of correlation are you using?

Comment: @saulspatz Thanks. I'm using Corr(X,Y) = Cov(X,Y)/(SD(X) * SD(Y))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The covariance of $X$ with the portfolio is

$$E(X(0.4X+0.4Y+0.2Z))-E(X)E(0.4X+0.4Y+0.2Z)$$

Expand this and use the assumptions.

Comment: @saulpatz -- Finance is not mathematics.

Comment: That probably explains why I can't make sense of the given solution.  Is this simple enough for you to give me a quick explanation of what is intended?

Comment: @saulpatz  - For simplicity, assume that a portfolio, by definition, is a finite convex combination of vectors in a Hilbert space. The covariance of any other vector in the space with this portfolio is simply the inner product of that vector with the portfolio. That is how you could make some rigorous sense out of it. In the Financial industry, however, they don't care about Hilbert spaces. They just compute covariances until they can compute no further.